# Kubuntu 16.04 lock session

Tags: kde, lock-screen, plasma

Trying to unbind Windows key +L. All my settings within KDE are set to alt+ctl+L to Lock. How do I remove this binding?

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Application Menu>System>System Settings>Keyboard & Mouse>Global Keyboard Shortcuts</strike>

Source:
https://www.maketecheasier.com/configure-custom-shortcuts-in-kde/

My bad. They actually have removed this capability from KDE.

Please take a look at the following bookmark "kbd-modifying" in the KDE docs:

https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/fundamentals/kbd.html#kbd-modifying

Comment: I don't have that path. I have System Settings > Workspace > Shortcuts there I have defined ctrl+alt+L and then System Settings > Work Spaace > Desktop Behavior > Screen Locking as well

Comment: I am so sorry, I was wrong. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Ahh. I still don't see the option to remove the binding because I don't know where the Meta+L binding is defined.